# How do I view the Applescript dictionary for "System Events"?

Tags: applescript

The only technique I know of for getting an app's Applescript Dictionary to appear is to drop the app's icon onto "Script Editor". This doesn't work with SE since it has no icon.

I need someone to tell me **EXACTLY** what to do step-by-step to view SE's dictionary.

I am running El Capitan if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In Script Editor press <kbd>⇧⌘O</kbd> (Open Dictionary)
- In the list select `System Events`
- Press <kbd>Return</kbd>

Comment: Is there a list of those symbols and their meaning anywhere?

Comment: Do you mean the key combinations? It's just [Inline HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html), plain text in `kbd` tags.

Comment: In Finder select Menu Edit > Emoji & Symbols then click on the » symbol at right bottom and then on the ⌘ symbol. To get more information click on the expander (top right).